# Export dxf file to shp with QGIS3

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, qgis-3

I want to export dxf file to shp with geometry type is LineString

```
input = 'D:\projet_2018\myfile.dxf'
output= 'D:\projet_2018\myfile.shp'
processing.run('gdal:convertformat',{ 'INPUT' : input, 
                                   'GEOMETRYTYPE' : 'LineString',
                                   'OUTPUT' : output}
                                )
```

It is not working, and how do I do to have the files `prj` and `qrj`